# Chrysler Sebring won't start

Tags: starting, chrysler, sebring

IT'S about 32 degrees out, not sure if that matters. When I went to start my 2007 Chrysler Sebring it just clicked a few times, but wouldn't start
 What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

### In general, car batteries don't like cold weather

Especially if they are weak/considerably discharged. The colder the outside temperature is, the lesser the amperage the battery will be able to deliver. This results in slower turning speeds, which if severe enough, will result in the audible clicking that indicates the starter motor is unable to turn the engine.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking usually suggests the battery doesn't have enough power to turn over the starter motor. Check the battery voltage, or try getting a jump from another vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

My main commuter car is a Chrysler Sebring 2001.  I have heard that "clicking" sound enough times over the years.  The problem is very likely a weakly charged battery.  Get a cheap portable jumper for the immediate problem.  Best thing in the long run is to get a $20 to $30 "Battery Tender Jr." which is a block that trickle charges your car's lead acid battery from your home's AC power.  It has firmware that specifically conditions the lead acid battery as well helping to extend the lead acid battery's life.  Lead acid batteries do not like to be fully discharged and actually be chemically damaged shortening their life.